# Why specify compile flags for YouCompleteMe vim plugin to work with C++?

Tags: c++, vim, plugins

I do not know how YouCompleteMe works. I am curious why it is necessary to specify compile flags in .ycm_extra_conf.py to autocomplete your C++ code?

Answer (score 0):

YCM uses clang's autocompletion support(`clang -cc1 -code-completion-at`) to provide semantic completion. Clang does this by parsing the translation unit. In order to do this, it needs the relevant compile flags - include directories and macro definitions, and this is why YCM needs it as well.

Comment: Do I need to specify include directories for the standart library (std)? How can I find include directories?

Comment: No you don't. The compiler is able to find that.